# What permission is required to edit a profile using direct URL?

Tags: profile, permissions, checksum

I am sending an email with customised link so that users can edit their information directly using the link like this [http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/proﬁle/edit?reset=1&gid=2&id=](http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/pro%EF%AC%81le/edit?reset=1&gid=2&id=){contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}

But users click on it they receive message "You do not have permission to edit this contact record. Contact the site administrator if you need assistance."
How to fix it please?

Comment: What CMS and CiviCRM version are you using?

Comment: drupal & civicrm 4.6.11

Comment: It looks like an ACL issue, although I'm not a Drupal user I'll try to help. I believe you can do this either with Drupal permission or CiviCRM ACL, for Civi navigate to **Administer > User and Permissions > Permissions > Drupal Access Control** and make sure that **Profile Create, Profile Edit and Profile View** are checked for Authenticated/Anonymous user, if the profile includes custom fields you must also check **Access all custom data**. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Its all checked for that is related to profile and custom fields. but Still the user information does not autofill.

Comment: So the profile does work now but it doesn't auto-fill the contact's custom data?

Comment: That's correct.